# Box2d setTransform

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, box2d

Set the scene:
• Our environment: LibGdx Android & iOS //If you don't know LibGdx, it's fine, just know that this program is being build for iOS and Android

• Our screen has nothing on it, just a Box2d Circle

Okay, so, what do I need to do?
**I need to make my Box2d Circle to "teleport" to where the screen is tapped... but I need it to have some velocity so if it collides w/ something else it will throw the other object out of its way.**

I am currently using body.setTransform() but I have no velocity and people say it is very buggy.

How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: `setTransform` is not actually buggy (as much as i know), but it does not use any physics, which usually is not the disired behavior. If you want the `circle` to have velocity after being teleported, then you can simply add an impact to it, as soon as it has been teleported. If the teleport itself should throw objects out of it's way, you might teleport the object near to the teleport point and move it (verry fast) to the teleport-point.

Comment: i have already try to use settransform() in one of my games, but my physics body had Jointure with other budies so it didn't work like i wanted, so i did this to teleport my bodies : destroy them at a point and re-create them at another point and it works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **setTransform** method is not buggy itself. **It can cause some troubles because of ignoring physics which can appear when**:

- **using joints** - joints provide some constraint and this "violent" change can make bodies behave weird
- **collision exists** - because the transformed body can be "pushed" into other body

The situation you are describing is totally typical situation when **setTransform** is being used and I see no reason here to be afraid of it. You don't need any velocity here also.

---

However, if you decide to change the "teleporting" mechanism to applying the velocity to move object to the world point you should:

- calculate velocity vector by subtracting target position and body position

  ```
  Vector2 velocity = target.sub( body.getPosition() ) ); //where target is Vector2 of touched point
  ```
- limit the velocity to some maximum I guess **if you need to** (this is optional)

  ```
  //optional
  velocity.nor();
  velocity.mul( MAX_VALUE ); //MAX_VALUE is a float
  ```
- set the velocity to the body

  ```
  body.setLinearVelocity( velocity );
  ```
- add to main loop (render method) check if the body is in target position (or in some range - due to precision there is small chance that it will precisely at the target if you will limit the velocity - if not I guess it should be in the target position after one iteration of world.update() )

  ```
  if( body.getPosition().sub( target ).len() < SOME_PRECISION )
  {
      body.setLinearVelocity( new Vector2(0, 0) );
  }
  ```

You can also take a look at Box2D [MouseJoint](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/joints/MouseJoint.html) although I've been never using this and cannot provide any hint here.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will have to try this out in a few hours

Comment: Worked Perfect! Just now... My Balls speed is stuck at a max speed (that I didn't set)... Any Ideas?

Comment: How is it stuck? What is happening?

Comment: @m.antkawicz The object will go a certain speed & then go no faster. Looked around the internet and many people have the same problem with no solution. Some suggested applying force... although... that didn't work for me, or maybe I did the math wrong.

Comment: how many meters you have for a pixel? Box2d has a limit of speed (120m per second when 60fps) - if you are not using any conversion you may have this problem

Answer (score 0):

Place the **setTransform()** code in the **LibGDX Gdx.app.postRunnable()** method:

```
Gdx.app.postRunnable {
    body.setTransform(10f, 10f, 0f)
}
```